# Iterating in two extremely large files simultaneously in Java

Tags: java, memory-management, large-files

I need to merge two very large files (>1G each) by writing 4 lines from the first into an output file, than write 4 from the second. And so on till the end. Both files have same number of lines and this number is divisible by four. What's the most efficient way to do it in Java?

Comment: The size of the file isn't that important. It's how you read it.

Comment: I would guess read 4 lines from one, write them, read 4 lines from the other, write them.  Use buffered readers/writers to get the efficiency.

Comment: It's probably more efficient to not use Java. The right combination of Linux command-line tools will likely be faster.

Comment: what about split file into small chunk (divide & conquer) ? 1. count total line num of file 2. split file into chunk using total line num 3. for each chunk, generate merged file. 4. combine merged file into result.

Comment: @kingori, that could work, but it's unnecessarily complex.  There's nothing wrong with just opening and reading both files sequentially; you only need to hold 8 lines (4 from each file) in memory at a time, so it doesn't matter how large the files are.

Comment: BTW, I edited your tags to better reflect the nature of the question.  Remember that each tag should be meaningful on its own; they don't form a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I love to use `Decorator` pattern. Create two classes, each class represents a BufferedReader instance.

For instance,

```
class First
{
   BufferedReader br;
   ...
   public String getLine()
    {
       return br.readLine();
     }
}

class Second
{
  BufferedReader br;
  ...
  public String [] getLines()
   {
     //read four lines and return it
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and see how long it takes. adjust n accordingly. if it's too slow try using nio.

```
import java.io.*;
class Time {
    Time() {}
    long dt() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - t0;
    }
    final long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
public class Main {
    public static void create(File file1, File file2, int n) throws Exception {
        BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1));
        write(bw1, n, "foo");
        bw1.close();
        BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file2));
        write(bw2, n, "bar");
        bw2.close();
    }
    private static void write(BufferedWriter bw, int n, String line) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            bw.write(line);
            bw.write(lineSeparator);
        }
    }
    private static void write4(BufferedReader br1, BufferedWriter bw, String line) throws IOException {
        bw.write(line);
        bw.write(lineSeparator);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            line = br1.readLine();
            bw.write(line);
            bw.write(lineSeparator);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file1 = new File("file1");
        File file2 = new File("file2");
        if (!file1.exists()) {
            create(file1, file2, 10000000);
        }
        File file3 = new File("file3");
        Time time=new Time();
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file3));
        String line1, line2;
        while ((line1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {
            write4(br1, bw, line1);
            line2 = br2.readLine();
            write4(br2, bw, line2);
        }
        br1.close();
        br2.close();
        bw.close();
        System.out.println(time.dt()/1000.+" s.");
    }
    static final String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this idea was already given :)

I think the fastest way to do this is by creating 3 threads. t1 & t2 will be reading from the two input files, each thread will have its own queue (which is thread safe) and the thread will read 4 lines and put them in its queue. t3 will be the writing thread, it will interchangeably read nodes from the two queues and put them in the new merged file. I think this is a good solution because it allows parallel i\o to all three files (and i\o is the bottle neck here..) and minimum interaction between the threads.